# Get pixels cords from specific angle

Tags: python, pygame

I have some problem. I'm using pygame. I would like to take cords of all pixels that are away from one point at a specific angle.

For example, I would like to get cords of all pixels that are away from point (15,20) at an angle of 18%.

I know there are some math to do but I cant figure out how to do this in python. Could you help me?

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Can you please explain this further.  Which co-ordinates, in what volume?  A 1-pixel thin straight line? A Conic-projection? Of what shape?  I could argue that half the 2D number-plane is beyond 18° from some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want the pixels in a line from ⟪some point⟫ going off in ⟪some angle⟫.

First let's define some things.

```
 origin_point  = ( 15, 20 )            # Co-ordinates of starting point
 project_angle = math.radians( 18.0 )  # Angle of projection in degrees
```

We need to change the angle from degrees to radians for the Python math trigonometric functions.  It's not just Python that uses radians, most programming languages do.

We want to define the line that goes from the `origin_point` in the direction of `project_angle`.  By working out the end-points of the line, it allows us to calculate the pixels.  So where does the line end? Infinity?  Probably the edge of screen will do.

We need to work out the intersection of the line formed with the edge of the screen, so we can use any sort of length for the line, so long as it's theoretically greater than the screen's *maximum possible* line-length (which is the diagonal: `diagonal_length = √(window_width² + window_length²)` ).  So any "long enough" length will do, so we'll cheat and use a constant of 10000.

```
MAX_LENGTH = 10000
```

Now for that co-ordinate... using the sine and cosine of the angle, multiply by the length to work out that point:

```
final_x = start_x + ( length * math.cos( angle_of_projection ) )
final_y = start_y + ( length * math.sin( angle_of_projection ) )
```

Turning this into a function:

```
def getEndOfLine( start_point, angle_of_projection, length ):
    """ Given a co-ordinate, projection angle, and line length, return
        the co-ordinate of the end of line """
    start_x, start_y = start_point
    final_x = start_x + length * math.cos( angle_of_projection )
    final_y = start_y + length * math.sin( angle_of_projection )
    return ( final_x, final_y )
```

Using this function, we can now do something like:

```
end_point = getEndOfLine( origin_point, project_angle, MAX_LENGTH )
```

Giving us two points to define the line.  So, now we have a line, we can intersect that with the screen edges.  Because our line is so long, it's guaranteed to exit the screen somewhere.

Where are the edges of the screen - these are easy to know:

```
top_side    = [ ( 0, 0 ), ( SCREEN_WIDTH-1, 0 ) ]
bottom_side = [ ( 0, SCREEN_HEIGHT-1 ), ( SCREEN_WIDTH-1, SCREEN_HEIGHT-1 ) ]
left_side   = [ ( 0, 0 ), ( SCREEN_WIDTH-1, SCREEN_HEIGHT-1 ) ]
right_side  = [ ( SCREEN_WIDTH-1, 0 ), ( SCREEN_WIDTH-1, SCREEN_HEIGHT-1 ) ]
all_sides = [ top_side, right_side, bottom_side, left_side ]
```

Now we need to intersect the angled-line with the screen-edge lines.  I don't want to go into the maths too much here, but if two, straight, infinitely-long lines are not parallel they *must* intersect. So first determine that your lines are *not* parallel, then calculate the intersection point using [the determinant method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection).  The lines might intersect off-screen, we don't care about these points.

```
def intersectionPoint( x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4 ):
    #Use determinant method, as per
    #Ref: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection
    Px = ((((x1*y2)-(y1*x2))*(x3 - x4)) - ((x1-x2)*((x3*y4)-(y3*x4)))) / (((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2)*(x3-x4)))
    Py = ((((x1*y2)-(y1*x2))*(y3 - y4)) - ((y1-y2)*((x3*y4)-(y3*x4)))) / (((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2)*(x3-x4)))
    return Px,Py

def getIntersectionPoint( line_start, line_end, screen_edges ):
    x1, y1 = line_start
    x2, y2 = line_end

    for edge in screen_edges:
        x3, y3 = edge[0]  # line forming the screen edge
        x4, y4 = edge[1]
        is_parallel = (((x1-x2)*(y3-y4)) - ((y1-y2)*(x3-x4)) == 0)

        if ( not is_parallel ):
           int_x, int_y = intersectionPoint( x1,y1, x2,y2, x3,y3, x4,y4 )
           # but is the intersection point on-screen (otherwise we don't care)
           if ( int_x >= 0 and int_y >= 0 and int_x < SCREEN_WIDTH and int_y < SCREEN_HEIGHT ):
               return ( int_x, int_y )

    return None  # should never happen
```

So now using this function, we can determine the point at the edge of the screen:

```
# Work out the long long line:
peliminary_point = getEndOfLine( origin_point, project_angle, MAX_LENGTH )
print( "Peliminary End Point from %3.1f° is (%3.1f,%3.1f)" % ( project_angle, peliminary_point[0], peliminary_point[1] ) )

# Work out where this line exits the screen/window:
end_point = getIntersectionPoint( origin_point, peliminary_point, all_sides )
print( "End Point is (%3.1f,%3.1f)" % ( end_point[0], end_point[1] ) )
```

For a 200x200 window, and MAX_LENGTH of 10000 I get:

> Peliminary End Point from 0.31° is (38052.3,12370.7)
>   End Point is (199.0,71.4)

Now we have the co-ordinate of the end of the line, it's easy to use [Bresenhnam's Midpoint Line Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham%27s_line_algorithm) to calculate the pixels.  Best go read about this, I'm not going to explain it here (not even sure I could).

```
def _plotLineLow( x0,y0, x1,y1 ):
    points = []
    dx = x1 - x0
    dy = y1 - y0
    yi = 1
    if dy < 0:
        yi = -1
        dy = -dy
    D = 2*dy - dx
    y = y0

    for x in range( x0, x1 ):
        points.append( (x,y) )
        if D > 0:
           y = y + yi
           D = D - 2*dx
        D = D + 2*dy
    return points

def _plotLineHigh( x0,y0, x1,y1 ):
    points = []
    dx = x1 - x0
    dy = y1 - y0
    xi = 1
    if dx < 0:
        xi = -1
        dx = -dx
    D = 2*dx - dy
    x = x0

    for y in range( y0, y1 ):
        points.append( (x,y) )
        if D > 0:
            x = x + xi
            D = D - 2*dy
        D = D + 2*dx
    return points

def getMidLinePoints( pointA, pointB ):
    x0, y0 = int( pointA[0] ), int( pointA[1] )
    x1, y1 = int( pointB[0] ), int( pointB[1] )
    points = []
    if ( abs(y1 - y0) < abs(x1 - x0) ):
        if ( x0 > x1 ):
            points += _plotLineLow( x1, y1, x0, y0 )
        else:
            points += _plotLineLow( x0, y0, x1, y1 )
    else:
        if ( y0 > y1 ):
            points += _plotLineHigh( x1, y1, x0, y0 )
        else:
            points += _plotLineHigh( x0, y0, x1, y1 )
    return points
```

Adding in this code, gives the co-ordinates of the pixels along the line from `origin_point` at `project_angle` to the edge of the screen:

```
# Work out the long long line:
peliminary_point = getEndOfLine( origin_point, project_angle, MAX_LENGTH )
print( "Peliminary End Point from %3.1f° is (%3.1f,%3.1f)" % ( project_angle, peliminary_point[0], peliminary_point[1] ) )

# Work out where this line exits the screen/window:
end_point = getIntersectionPoint( origin_point, peliminary_point, all_sides )
print( "End Point is (%3.1f,%3.1f)" % ( end_point[0], end_point[1] ) )

line_points = getMidLinePoints( origin_point, end_point )
print( "Line Points are: " + str( line_points ) )
```

Which gives me (this time on a 100x100 window):

> Peliminary End Point from 0.31° is (9520.6,3100.2)
>   End Point is (99.0,38.9)
>   Line Points are: [(10, 10), (11, 10), (12, 11), (13, 11), (14, 11), (15, 12), (16, 12), (17, 12), (18, 13), (19, 13), (20, 13), (21, 13), (22, 14), (23, 14), (24, 14), (25, 15), (26, 15), (27, 15), (28, 16), (29, 16), (30, 16), (31, 17), (32, 17), (33, 17), (34, 18), (35, 18), (36, 18), (37, 18), (38, 19), (39, 19), (40, 19), (41, 20), (42, 20), (43, 20), (44, 21), (45, 21), (46, 21), (47, 22), (48, 22), (49, 22), (50, 23), (51, 23), (52, 23), (53, 24), (54, 24), (55, 24), (56, 24), (57, 25), (58, 25), (59, 25), (60, 26), (61, 26), (62, 26), (63, 27), (64, 27), (65, 27), (66, 28), (67, 28), (68, 28), (69, 29), (70, 29), (71, 29), (72, 30), (73, 30), (74, 30), (75, 30), (76, 31), (77, 31), (78, 31), (79, 32), (80, 32), (81, 32), (82, 33), (83, 33), (84, 33), (85, 34), (86, 34), (87, 34), (88, 35), (89, 35), (90, 35), (91, 35), (92, 36), (93, 36), (94, 36), (95, 37), (96, 37), (97, 37), (98, 38)]

Pretty simple heh!  `;)`